# Modify maxRecordsPerFile in an existing Hive table in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

Is it possible to change the table properties `maxRecordsPerFile`, after a table is created?

For example, I create first a table setting `maxRecordsPerFile`:

```
df = (
   spark.createDataFrame(
         data=[[i, "a"] for i in range(100000)], schema=["index", "col1"])
).coalesce(1)
(
    df.write
    .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000)
    .partitionBy("col1").saveAsTable("myTable")
)
```

The initial 100k columns are split into 10 files, each with 10k rows.
The option is saved as a table property:

```
spark.sql("SHOW TBLPROPERTIES myTable").show(truncate=False)
+------------------------+-----+
|key                     |value|
+------------------------+-----+
|option.maxRecordsPerFile|10000|
+------------------------+-----+
```

If I try to modify the property:

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE myTable SET TBLPROPERTIES (option.maxRecordsPerFile=20000)")
```

The parameters doesn't change, and it is still set to 10000. If I add more data using:

```
df.withColumn("col1", f.lit("b")).write.insertInto("myTable")
```

A new partition is added, with again 10 files of 10k rows.
Is there a way to modify the `maxRecordPerFile` option, after the table is created and insert new data with the new configuration?

Comment: I found the solution:
`ALTER TABLE myTable SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('maxRecordsPerFile'='50000')`